# Display slide with two records at a time

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display slide with two records at a time. Now I am only getting only one record at a time in slider because I fetch data in while loop. My code is:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <?php 
    ...
    while($eventData = mysql_fetch_array($eventSql))
    {
    ?>
        <li class="questions-slide-item">
            <div class="query clearfix">
                <div class="image fl">
                    <img src='<?php echo $eventData['image']; ?>' style="width:63px; height:61px;">
                </div>                                                 
            </div> 
        </li> 
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a counter and open/close the list item only every second iteration:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li class="questions-slide-item">
        <?php 
        ...
        $count = 0;
        while($eventData = mysql_fetch_array($eventSql))
        {
            if($count > 0 && $count % 2 == 0) {
        ?>
                </li>
                <li class="questions-slide-item">
        <?php
            }
        ?>


            <div class="query clearfix">
            <div class="image fl">
            <img src='<?php echo $eventData['image']; ?>' style="width:63px; height:61px;">
            </div>                                                 
            </div> 



        <?php 
            $count++;
        } 
        ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first take all the rows in one array and then use that array as per your needs.

See to following code to understand what I am trying to say.

```
<?php 
    ...
    $eventData= array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($eventSql)) 
    {
        $eventData [] = $row;
    }
    for($i=0;count($eventData);$i=$i+2)
    {
    ?>
        <li class="questions-slide-item">

        <div class="query clearfix">
        <div class="image fl">
        <img src='<?php echo $eventData[$i]['image']; ?>' style="width:63px; height:61px;">
        </div>                                                 
        </div> 
        </li> 

        <li class="questions-slide-item">

        <div class="query clearfix">
        <div class="image fl">
        <img src='<?php echo $eventData[$i+1]['image']; ?>' style="width:63px; height:61px;">
        </div>                                                 
        </div> 
        </li> 
    <?php } ?>
```